# Addition of Properties within Object Literal produces NaN

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, object-literal

Could someone help me undertand why I am getting NaN when adding two properties of an object literal together as the definition of a third property?

Here's a code example, and I created a Codepen too.

(http://codepen.io/Tristan-zimmerman/pen/cvJFE)

```
objLiteral = {
 numberOne : 50,
 numberTwo : 80,
 mathStuff : this.numberOne + this.numberTwo,
};

console.log(objLiteral.mathStuff);
//Logs NaN.
```

When I use the constructor to instantiate a new object I get correct math:

```
function objConstructor () {
  this.numberOne = 50;
  this.numberTwo = 80;
  this.mathStuff = this.numberOne + this.numberTwo;
}

var objConstructed = new objConstructor();

console.log(objConstructed.mathStuff);
//Logs 130.
```

As you can see in the Codepen example I have an object literal, and then the properties are appended to the body in the results frame. I'm also logging 'this' from the Object literal to make sure that the scope is correct and that is is in fact referencing the object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the object literal in it's definition, you should create a function for that, [check this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tvgsx)

In it I've defined objectLiteral as:

```
objLiteral = {
 numberOne : 50,
 numberTwo : 80,
 mathStuff : function() {
    return this.numberOne + this.numberTwo;
 }
};

objLiteral.matchStuff(); //130
```

That way `this` will be the object, otherwise it'll be `window` because the object does not exists at that time (and window it's the default scope)

Also, I recommend you search more on this topic, one good (and free) resource [is this book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000262/index.html)

Comment: Thanks! this really looks like it solved my problem. I knew was missing some fundamental part of how Javascript was functioning, but I couldn't seem to find any info when searching for it.

Thanks for the code example and book suggestion too. I passed them both around to my colleagues so they could bask in the learning.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the object literal, `this` is referring to the global scope (where `numberOne` and `numberTwo` remain undefined). The `function` keyword creates the local scope you want.